# power query - find what does not match in two tables

Tags: excel, match, powerquery

[image: Query editor view]

I have two tables, both have 29 identical column names. I want to find out which record does not match and I want to know exactly which (one or more) columns that do not match in the record. Each record has a uniqueID that matches in each table.

Is there a relatively easy custom column I could write to compare the two columns and "output" where the matches fail?

I already have a way to check if the total sum of all columns are equal, which works. Now i want to focus in on which columns i have a mismatch in.

Example of what i would like to do, matching column1 with column1, column2 with column2:
[image]

Comment: Probably not an "easy" solution.  I'd think you'd have to either write a function that does a `List.Difference` on each column; or combine the tables. See if [this](https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/how-to-compare-two-tables-using-get-and-transform/) helps.

Comment: I already have a way to determine if "something" does not match between a record in each table. I found a vba for creating a hash and compare the two. Your link essentially does the same though i have to manually compare the results there. I have name of the record and want to find out if it is value in column4, value in column8, value in column22 that does not match.

Comment: Then there's probably not an "easy" custom column you can write.  For more focused assistance, I suggest you edit your question to show simplified data sample, desired output, what you have, and the problem with what you have. To do this better, I'd suggest reading the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)